# How to deploy gwt static pages in jboss

Tags: gwt, jboss, web-deployment

I have some static files ( html, javascript, css - compiled gwt client code). I need to deploy that files in jboss.

That is I need to access like  `http://localhost:8080/Client/homepage.html` .
Where do I need to put the files in jboss.

I tried putting it in
`D:\Program Files\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy\Client\homepage.html`
restarted the server and tried to access
`http://localhost:8080/Client/homepage.html`.
 But it shows `404` error.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename Client folder to Client.war, the example will work.

You don´t need to do anything special to deploy static files, just place them in a valid war and that´s it. By valid war I mean having a WEB-INF folder with your web descriptor inside (web.xml), lib and classes folder, etc..

It is shown here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html